# First Day of the Week Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to get the first day of the week (first day is Sunday) in 'MM/DD/YY format. Here's my Oracle code. I just can't figure out how to in Postgres:

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(column_name + 1,'IW') - 1, 'MM/DD/YY')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [date_trunc()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

```
date_trunc('week', column_name)
```

It uses the ISO definition of a week (as does Oracle's `'IW'`) so you need to apply the same date logic you used in Oracle to get the non-standard start of the week:

```
date_trunc('week', column_name + 1) - 1
```